# Reanimated Tried to synchronously call a non-worklet function on the Ul thread when using Skia

Tags: react-native

Whenever i use react-native-reanimated hooks like withTiming , useSharedValue ,  useDervideValue or useComputedValue with skia it throws an error , I know i must use a "worklet" decorative inside functions or runOnJs   but it doesn’t work , even when i use skia's example it throws error :
https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/animations/animations/

And here is the error:
[image]
I don't know what's the problem, i even used runOnJs , but it didn't work.
Skia version is "^0.1.222" and reanimated version is "^3.5.4".
How can i fix this?

Comment: Same problem here. I used the same code from an old project that works on a new project and I got that same error when I render an animated view with entering animation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I updated the package `npm i react-native-reanimated@3.7.0` then build a new development build and now the error is gone.